# How to create Migration File in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, postgresql, mongoid

I am using mongodb and postgresql databases for my project. Mongodb is used for performing social activities like chatting and messaging, Postgresql is maintained for monitoring the user's transactions.

If i use **rails g model model_name** or if i use **rails g migration migration_filename** it shows the following error.

```
WARNING: Nokogiri was built against LibXML version 2.8.0, but has dynamically loaded 2.7.8
       error  mongoid [not found]
```

By default it takes only for mongodb. But I want to create a model for postgresql.

Thanks in advance

Can anyone please tell me what change to be made to create an model with migration files for postgresql even if i use mongodb.